# Why is 'logger' always executed as the same user?

Tags: debian, syslog, rsyslog

I'm using `rsyslog 8.24` on debian. Each time I trigger `logger "some message"` the syslog refers to the same and only system user - it does not matter if I switch user (even as `root`), the messages are always logged as the same user - even on servers - I guess on a desktop, it's because the GUI is running as that user and on a server because I logged in as that user and later switch to `root` - could that be? But anyway, how could I log a message as `root` to the syslog?

Comment: What is the user that `logger` logs?

Comment: It's my default system user I use to login to X11 or SSH on servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `logger` uses `getlogin(3)`.

https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/logger.c#L379

```
static char const *xgetlogin(void)
{
    char const *cp;
    struct passwd *pw;

    if (!(cp = getlogin()) || !*cp)
        cp = (pw = getpwuid(geteuid()))? pw->pw_name : "<someone>";
    return cp;
}
```

Which returns "name of the user logged in on the controlling terminal of the process".  i.e. your system user.